# WCF service fails when configuring InstanceContextMode as Single with Autofac wcf integration

Tags: wcf, autofac, interceptor

I am facing an issue with Autofac WCF Integration when I configure the service to be Singleton. If I remove the InstanceContextMode and Singletion autofac configuration, then service works fine. I have also configured Autofac Interceptors, and they also work fine without Singleton configuration.
Also, point to note that if I remove the interceptor from autofac component registration, then also WCF works fine with InstanceContextMode set as Single.
But I need to have the WCF working with Interceptors and InstanceContextMode as Single both, and this combination isn't working.
Any help is appreciated.

Attached image shows the error I am getting and also link to github repo is provided below with the sample application.

[image]

https://github.com/devlic1/AutofacWCFTest

Comment: Please read [ask]- particularly the section on helping others reproduce the issue.

Comment: @starball I have provided the GitHub repo link, the issue can be reproduced in the repo easily

Comment: According to the error message, both classes define and inherit service agreements, which appears to be a conflict.

Comment: @Jiayao The error is misleading. I only have ServiceContract attribute on the Interface, not on Class. Secondly, as I mentioned, if I remove the interceptor or remove Singleton registration, then things are working fine.

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also posted this issue in Autofac WCF github issues but didn't get any solution. https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Wcf/issues/31

Hence, I am posting my workaround as it may help someone.

I am using EnableClassInterceptors(as EnableInterfaceInterceptors was causing issue ) technique and I create the method Virtual in my class to be intercepted.

Interceptor class

```
public class Interceptor : Castle.DynamicProxy.IInterceptor
{
    public Interceptor() { }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        invocation.Proceed();

        invocation.ReturnValue = invocation.ReturnValue + "value changed from Interceptor";
    }
}
```

Service class

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }

    public virtual string Test(string input)
    {
        //Call any base implementation if needed
        return "Test Passed " + Convert.ToString(input);
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<WCFService.Service1>()
               .As<ClassLibrary1.IService1>()
               .SingleInstance()
               .EnableClassInterceptors().InterceptedBy(typeof(Interceptor));

        builder.Register(c => new Interceptor());

        AutofacHostFactory.Container = builder.Build();
    }
```