# autofac - Not able to use EnableClassInterceptors with expression registration or lambda registration techniuqe

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, autofac

Below is my normal registration line for the Service and it was working fine till now. I have to use EnableClassInterceptors and I can't use EnableInterfaceInterceptors because of reason provided here [Can't use EnableInterfaceInterceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75109462/wcf-service-fails-when-configuring-instancecontextmode-as-single-with-autofac-wc)

```
  builder.RegisterType<Service>().As<IService>().PropertiesAutowired().SingleInstance().EnableClassInterceptors().InterceptedBy(typeof(MyInterceptor));
```

Now, for some reason, the we had to add a constructor parameter to Service, and that constructor parameter type is registered as Named registration in container. So now, above registration is failing as it is not able to resolve that parameter by it's own.
I have the option to use registration expression where I can resolve all constructor parameters manually and create the Service object, but it causes me unable to use the EnableClassInterceptors because of below error

Error   CS0311  The type 'Autofac.Builder.SimpleActivatorData' cannot be used as type parameter 'TConcreteReflectionActivatorData' in the generic type or method 'RegistrationExtensions.EnableClassInterceptors<TLimit, TConcreteReflectionActivatorData, TRegistrationStyle>(IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TConcreteReflectionActivatorData, TRegistrationStyle>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Autofac.Builder.SimpleActivatorData' to 'Autofac.Builder.ConcreteReflectionActivatorData'.

I wanted to know the way to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

From the error point of view, it should be a problem with the variable. **Autofac.Builder.SimpleActivatorData** is of a different type from **Autofac.Builder.ConcreteReflectionActivatorData**, with different attributes and behaviors.

Try this code:

```
c => new ConcreteReflectionActivatorData(c.Resolve<SimpleActivatorData>())
```

What this code means is to create a new instance of the **ConcreteReflectionActivatorData** class and initialize it with the data parsed from **SimpleActivatorData**.